# turning off the lazy evaluation in django

Tags: python, authentication, django-rest-framework, lazy-evaluation

**What is lazy evaluation?**

I read somewhere that it can cause a 403/401 authentication errors - I am getting a "Invalid username/password" on a simple authentication to django.

**and how do I turn it off in django rest framework?**

Thanks!

Comment: Lazy evaluation shouldn't be influencing an authentication issue. Your problem is that your username and password are not able to authenticate (can you log into the Django admin?), not that the queryset is being evaluated to early - trust me, it isn't.

Comment: @KevinBrown thanks for your comment. okay, so do you have an idea why isn't it authenticating? my question is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30548260/django-rest-framework-getting-an-error-on-basic-authentication?noredirect=1#comment49170681_30548260 I can't understand why isn't it working.. any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

The pattern that for example, methods like [django.db.models.query.QuerySet](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/trunk/django/db/models/query.py)  follow is that no queries are executed until some method that really needs to return some result is called. At that point, the result is stored in self._result_cache and any subsequent call to the same method returns the cached value.

Here you can see how it's used to optimize databases :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/optimization/

And here about Query sets being Lazy you can see it's just a manner of evaluation of Queries : 
 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/queries/#querysets-are-lazy

As far as I can tell you can't disable it, it's how the Querying system is coded.

It shouldn't be the reason for your problems.